# A combination of two tables to fill a distance D algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Assume two type of tables, the shorter is  X and the longer is Y. A combination of two types of tables are aligned to fill a distance D.  find the optimum combination to keep the remaining empty distance is as small as possible. 
the first priority is to minimize the empty distance
the second priority is to minimize the number of used tables

ex
Input: X = 3, Y = 5, D = 24
The optimum combination is: TX = 3, TY = 3, RD = 0
my solution based on while loop and if-else statements

```
 R=24
 X=3
 Y=5
 while(R>X):
   if R%Y==0:
      TY=R/Y
      R=0
   else if RD % X == 0:
      TX=R%X
      R=0
```

but not optimal solution

Comment: Hey Eman, This does not look to me like a primarily programming but math related question. You might have more success when asking that question (its math part of course) at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this algorithm is solved by java or any p language

Comment: do both the tables have to be used, or is it possible to use just 1 table?

Comment: I think this is absolutely a valid algorithm question in SO, similar as knapsack problem.

Comment: yes may be one table,

Comment: In other words, given three integers a, b, c, find integers x, y (>= 0) such that (a) xa + yb - c is minimal, and (b) x+y is minimal, right?

Comment: This is a valid & interesting question, why would anyone downvote it, LoL

Answer (score 0):

That was hard to understand, you are actually talking about tables to eat, and X and Y are the lengths of the tables, while D is the desired length you want to get by combining tables of lengths X and Y.

Here is a solution, assuming you have to find the smallest length >= D, otherwise some people don't have a seat (this solution also tries to take as many of the longer tables Y as possible if there are several ways to reach the optimum and therefore also minimizes the number of tables needed), *the **comments** show what you have to change to get the greatest number <= D*:

```js
function solve(x, y, d) {
    let tX = 0, tY = Math.ceil(d / y), tD = tY * y, // floor
        bestX = 0, bestY = tY, bestD = tD, seen = []
    while (tD != d && !seen[tD]) {
        seen[tD] = true
        tD = ++tX * x
        if (tD >= d) // if (tD > d) break
            return tD < bestD ? [tX, 0, tD - d] : [bestX, bestY, bestD - d]
        tY = Math.ceil((d - tD) / y) // floor
        tD += tY * y
        if (tD < bestD) { // tD > bestD
            bestX = tX
            bestY = tY
            bestD = tD
        }
    }
    return [bestX, bestY, bestD - d] // d - bestD
}

console.log(solve(3, 5, 24))
console.log(solve(64, 80, 999999981))
```

It is actually very simple, you just increment tX step by step, calculate the best tY for that tX and keep track of the best solution. To avoid repeating the same thing over and over again we keep track of the seen table lengths (it will be a cycle and if you encounter the same value again you know you have already seen the optimum). This is useful for inputs like X = 64, Y = 80 and D = 999999981 (note it is odd and can't ever be reached). It finds the solution TX = 1, TY = 12499999 and RD = 3 almost immediately.

Comment: There seems to have 1 issue, the output length should max length that <= desired length, not the opposite. Because the question says `minimize the empty distance`, which implies there is a gap, but not extra space.

Comment: @EricWang I think it leaves room for interpretation, I thought empty because there are no people sitting there, which would imply it has to be >= desired length. Anyway I already added comments how to change it, so that it is <= desired length.

Comment: Btw. you can verify that the solution is correct: 999999981 % 16 = 13 and 16 - 13 = 3, this is exactly the RD we are getting. 16 because it is the gcd of 64 and 80 and 999999981 is greater than 64 * 80 - 64 - 80 (the Frobenius number, actually not really, because the numbers would have to be coprime, but it works because if you round up 999999981 to the next multiple of 16 and then divide everything by 16 you have coprime numbers and a reachable result for which TX and TY will be the same).

Comment: BTW, I added an answer (assuming target length <= D), without recursion, it takes `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is an `O(1)` solution.
*(This answer assuming the question means the final length **<= D**, not the opposite.)*

---

### Logic

**Steps:**

```
* First, calculate initial max Y as b, then min X as a, and get a initial gap.
* if (gap > 0) && (Y % X >0), then:
    * figure out a group of X to replace a single Y, to reduce gap by Z,
    * reduce the gap by exhange Xs & Y,
    * re-calculate: a, b, gap,
* return new int[] {a, b, gap};
```

**Complexity**:

- Time: `O(1)`
- Space: `O(1)`

---

### Code *(`Java`)*

- **CombineTwoTables.java**

```
public class CombineTwoTables {
    public static int[] findByExchange(int X, int Y, int D) {
        int b = D / Y; // count of Y,
        int gap = D - b * Y; // gap left,

        int a = gap / X; // count of X,
        gap = gap - a * X;

        if (gap > 0) {
            int Z = Y % X;
            if (Z > 0) { // when Z == 0, any further step is useless,
                Z = X - Z;
                int exchanges = gap / Z;
                if (exchanges > 0) {
                    int xs = Y / X + 1; // count of x in each exchange,

                    a = a + exchanges * xs;
                    b = b - exchanges;
                    gap = gap - exchanges * Z;
                }
            }
        }

        return new int[]{a, b, gap};
    }
}
```

- **CombineTwoTablesTest.java**
  *(Test case, via `TestNG`)*

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CombineTwoTablesTest {
    @Test
    public void testFindByExchange() {
        runOnce(3, 5, 24, new int[]{3, 3, 0});

        runOnce(64, 80, 999999981, new int[]{2, 12499998, 13});

        runOnce(6, 10, 1026, new int[]{1, 102, 0});
        runOnce(6, 10, 1025, new int[]{4, 100, 1});
        runOnce(6, 10, 1024, new int[]{4, 100, 0});
        runOnce(6, 10, 1023, new int[]{2, 101, 1});
        runOnce(6, 10, 1022, new int[]{2, 101, 0});
        runOnce(6, 10, 1021, new int[]{0, 102, 1});
    }

    private void runOnce(int X, int Y, int D, int[] expected) {
        int[] result = CombineTwoTables.findByExchange(X, Y, D);
        System.out.printf("input: X = %d, Y = %d, D = %d,\texpected: %s,\tresult: %s\n", X, Y, D, Arrays.toString(expected), Arrays.toString(result));
        Assert.assertEquals(result, expected);
    }
}
```

All test case would **pass**, with output:

```
input: X = 3, Y = 5, D = 24,    expected: [3, 3, 0],    result: [3, 3, 0]
input: X = 64, Y = 80, D = 999999981,   expected: [2, 12499998, 13],    result: [2, 12499998, 13]
input: X = 6, Y = 10, D = 1026, expected: [1, 102, 0],  result: [1, 102, 0]
input: X = 6, Y = 10, D = 1025, expected: [4, 100, 1],  result: [4, 100, 1]
input: X = 6, Y = 10, D = 1024, expected: [4, 100, 0],  result: [4, 100, 0]
input: X = 6, Y = 10, D = 1023, expected: [2, 101, 1],  result: [2, 101, 1]
input: X = 6, Y = 10, D = 1022, expected: [2, 101, 0],  result: [2, 101, 0]
input: X = 6, Y = 10, D = 1021, expected: [0, 102, 1],  result: [0, 102, 1]
```

---

### Tips

- To make things more clear, operators like `+=`, `-=` are avoided, and use `=` instead.
- If you assume `target length >= D`, then probably there is a similar solution, though I didn't actually put a thought on it.